# Remover linhas de uma array numpy

Tags: python, array, numpy

Por exemplo eu tenho a array arr1 e quero tirar um intervalo de linha dessa array como abaixo, que função posso utilizar?

```
arr1:
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5],
       [ 6,  6,  6],
       [ 7,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  8,  8],
       [ 9,  9,  9],
       [10, 10, 10],
       [11, 11, 11],
       [12, 12, 12],
       [13, 13, 13],
       [14, 14, 14]])
```

Remover as linhas de 1 a 5 de arr1

```
array([[ 6,  6,  6],
       [ 7,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  8,  8],
       [ 9,  9,  9],
       [10, 10, 10],
       [11, 11, 11],
       [12, 12, 12],
       [13, 13, 13],
       [14, 14, 14]])
```

Remover as linhas de 6 a 10 de arr1

```
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5],
       [11, 11, 11],
       [12, 12, 12],
       [13, 13, 13],
       [14, 14, 14]])
```

Remover as linhas de 11 a 14 de arr1

```
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5],
       [ 6,  6,  6],
       [ 7,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  8,  8],
       [ 9,  9,  9],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Inicializar o array:

`a = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1], [ 2, 2, 2], [ 3, 3, 3], [ 4, 4, 4], [ 5, 5, 5], [ 6, 6, 6], [ 7, 7, 7], [ 8, 8, 8], [ 9, 9, 9], [10, 10, 10], [11, 11, 11], [12, 12, 12], [13, 13, 13], [14, 14, 14]])`

## Para remover as linhas de 1 a 5:

`para_remover = [i for i in range(0, 5)]`

`np.delete(a, para_remover, axis=0)`

Comment: Não teria um custo alto dessa maneira?

Comment: Esse foi o mais resumido que resolveu o problema. Valeu

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/numpy-slice)

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1], [ 2, 2, 2], [ 3, 3, 3], [ 4, 4, 4], [ 5, 5, 5], \
[ 6, 6, 6], [ 7, 7, 7], [ 8, 8, 8], [ 9, 9, 9], [10, 10, 10], [11, 11, 11], \
[12, 12, 12], [13, 13, 13], [14, 14, 14]])

# Removendo linhas de 1 a 5
a2 = a1[5:]

# Removendo linhas de 6 a 10
a3 = np.concatenate((a1[:5],a1[10:]), axis=0)

# Removendo linhas de 11 a 14
a4 = a1[:10]
```

Veja o resultado no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/numpy-slice).

Answer (score 1):

Removendo linha de 1 a 5:

```
>>> a[5:len(a)]
array([[ 6,  6,  6],
       [ 7,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  8,  8],
       [ 9,  9,  9],
       [10, 10, 10],
       [11, 11, 11],
       [12, 12, 12],
       [13, 13, 13],
       [14, 14, 14]])
```

removendo linha de 6 a 10:

```
>>> np.concatenate((a[0:5], a[10:len(a)]), axis=0)
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5],
       [11, 11, 11],
       [12, 12, 12],
       [13, 13, 13],
       [14, 14, 14]])
```

removendo linha de 11 a 14:

```
>>> a[0:10]
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5],
       [ 6,  6,  6],
       [ 7,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  8,  8],
       [ 9,  9,  9],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```

PS: lembrando que em Python os índices de arrays/vetores/listas sempre começam pelo número `0`

Comment: É a minha resposta. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Eu prefiro assim:

```
>>> sua_array = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1], [ 2, 2, 2], [ 3, 3, 3], [ 4, 4, 4], [ 5, 5, 5], \
[ 6, 6, 6], [ 7, 7, 7], [ 8, 8, 8], [ 9, 9, 9], [10, 10, 10], [11, 11, 11], \
[12, 12, 12], [13, 13, 13], [14, 14, 14]])

>>> np.delete(sua_array, np.s_[:5], axis=0) # deleta os 5 primeiros

>>> np.delete(sua_array, np.s_[5:10], axis=0) # deleta do 5 ao 10
```

etc..